# Spring Web: Correct way to have a single default ViewResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What is the best way to have every request be sent to a single ViewResolver - specifically in this case a JsonView?

Was thinking this:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="*" />
</bean>
```

but, is there something better/easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misunderstood what a `ViewResolver` is for. They're not there to service requests (that's what controllers are for), they're there [to turn view names (as returned by the controller) into views](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver) (e.g. JSPs). The `prefix` and `suffix` properties are used to assemble the path to the view.

If you could describe what problem you're trying to solve, we can show you how.

Comment: I am creating a rest endpoint that will return a Json response for a success/error giving details on what happened during the request.  In this case, do I even need to set up a viewResolver? or do I just have the controller method return a JsonView?

Comment: @wuntee: Sounds like you have no use for a `ViewResolver`, just return a `View` directly from the controller.